# embed a number and extension in a variable file name

Tags: matlab, for-loop, filenames, file-extension

I want to save data to files that have consecutive numbers in these file names within a for-loop.

first I have a function "SetConfeguration.m" in which I specifie the input directory and the file name as fields in a structure as below

```
StrConf.InputDirectory = 'C:/ElastixMatlab/elx_input';
StrConf.ParameterFilename = 'parameter.%d.txt';
```

the structure "StrConf" will be used as a parameter in the main function as below

```
ParameterFilename = fullfile(Conf.InputDirectory, Conf.ParameterFilename);
for Cpt = 1:NbParameterFiles
   TmpParameterFilename = sprintf(ParameterFilename, Cpt - 1);
   disp('ParameterFilename: '); disp(ParameterFilename);
end
```

I have the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid escape sequence appears in format string. See help sprintf for
valid escape sequences. 
> In elxElastix at 153
  In elxExampleStreet at 93

ParameterFilename : 
C:\ElastixMatlab\elx_input\parameter.%d.txt

TmpParameterFilename : 
C:
```

Comment: What language you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `sprintf` before `fullfile`.  The problem is that `fullfile` is normalizing your path separator from `/` used in your code, to `\` which is the standard on Windows.  But `\` is also used for escape sequences which sprintf recognizes.

This will work better:

```
for Cpt = 1:NbParameterFiles
   TmpParameterFilename = fullfile(Conf.InputDirectory, ...
                                   sprintf(StrConf.ParameterFilename, Cpt - 1));
   disp('ParameterFilename: '); TmpParameterFilename;
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Ben Voigt for your response,
it works finally

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to call the structure `StrConf` to access the parameters

```
TmpParameterFilename = sprintf(StrConf.ParameterFilename, Cpt - 1);
disp('ParameterFilename: '); disp(StrConf.ParameterFilename);
```

Also, i suggest you to make a little change in the for loop, since it loops from `0` to `n-1`.

```
ParameterFilename = fullfile(Conf.InputDirectory, Conf.ParameterFilename);
for Cpt = 0:NbParameterFiles-1
   TmpParameterFilename = sprintf(StrConf.ParameterFilename, Cpt);
   disp('ParameterFilename: '); disp(StrConf.ParameterFilename);
end
```

This way you save an operation in every iteration, since you don't make the substraction of `Cpt - 1`, making your code a little bit more efficient.

Comment: Thank you @eventHandler for your response,

the structure StrConf.ParameterFilename contains the filename and extension but not the directory, 

`code`StrConf.ParameterFilename = 'parameter.%d.txt';

that's why I used

ParameterFilename = fullfile(Conf.InputDirectory, Conf.ParameterFilename);

Thank you for your suggestion about the for-loop and I'll take it into consideration.

Comment: Now i see, i made lots of mistakes there... Glad to be helpful at least in that loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
  TmpParamterFilename = sprinf('%s%d.txt',ParameterFilename, Cpt-1);
```

And then ParameterFilename wouldn't have .txt at the end.

Comment: Sorry, meaning, change ParameterFilename so that it just has the path plus the filename without the suffix.